# Vuejs Issue with the second request having 300ms overhead

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I started learning Vuejs and I saw a strange behavior with the HTTP request to my web server. I'm using axios to make requests.
I just installed the vue-cli version 3.11 without using the webpack, and I added the config file vue.config.js next to package.json with the following content to proxy my web server

```
module.exports = {
 devServer: {
  port: 8081,
  proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
 }
};
```

Then using axios I'm trying to do a GET request by clicking a button

```
axios.get(API_URL, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
      }
}).then(response => {});
```

My web server based on Python and bottle where the API request of fetching users takes between 5ms and 16ms to be processed.
By opening the browser inspector I saw that on the second request I'm getting an overhead around 300ms, please see below:
[image]

Request and Response parameters
[image]
Anyone has an opinion about this behavior? I searched a bit for vue-cli 3 issues or CORS headers but I did not find anything helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your `Request` and `Response` params and headers for each two requests?

Comment: @SujitBaniya Of course. Just updated the question

Comment: There are no `Request` params. If you could share `Request|Response` params for each two requests

Comment: Are you sure you are passing ip address `127.0.0.1` instead of domain name? That happened to me when I had used domain name instead of direct ip

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Yes I have my web server running on "0.0.0.0" and under vue.config.js I have proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:8080". I also put under vue.config.js the host of client to be "127.0.0.1" but not luck

Comment: @SujitBaniya There are no request or response parameters the api url  is just "/hub/api/users". If this is not what you mean can you please assist where i can find those requests or response urls?

Comment: @Panagiotis Please check this: https://www.loom.com/share/cf13153e5ff84db7abb3d33a90aa73ec

I'm trying to see if both requests have different Request|Reponse structure under the hood

Comment: @SujitBaniya I checked the Chrome inspector and I'm not seeing any request payload there. Might be a browser bug? I'm doing a GET request so no form data passed to the API

Comment: @SujitBaniya Is this case reproducible on your machine?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Is this case reproducible on your machine?

Comment: I use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 without any problems

Comment: I tried also on different browsers like Edge and Firefox and I did not have the same behavior as Chrome. It is like Chrome does something more than that? What is your opinion?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov I would like your opinion on that. I changed on the browser the address from localhost:8081 to 127.0.0.1:8081 and there is not issue at all? Is something with the proxy settings in my vue.config.js. Am I missing something? My server runs on "0.0.0.0:8080"